# R: exporting formatted dataframe (with wordwrapping) to PDF **without** Rmarkdown

Tags: r, pdf, word-wrap, rscript

I'm trying to export a dataframe to a pdf file. My dataframe contains a column of text comments that are long, and so I would like to wrap the text in the table that would be produced within the .pdf. I already tried creating a table using grid.table and the pdf function, but I am not seeing any options for wrapping text. When I look up how to format a table, all the results seem to be talking about RMarkdown. My script has to be within an .R file, so I cannot knit it into a .pdf.

```
x <- data.frame("Question" = c("Comment1", "Comment2"), "Text"=c("This is one comments that's really long and I'd like the
                                                             width of the row to reflect that. I'd like it to wrap the text
                                                             so it is not cut off", "This is another comment that's really long and
                                                             gets cut off if I try to export to .pdf"))
```

Above is an example of a dataframe that I would like to export to a .pdf, using a wrap-text feature to control the width of the rows and not cut off the comments.

Is this possible?

Thank you!!

Best,
Kelly